# How to add a compound node using RDFLib?

Tags: python, rdflib

I'm new to using Python's RDFLib (so apologies for incorrect use of terms and such!), and am looking for a way to add the following to a node:

```
prov:qualifiedAssociation [ a prov:Association ; prov:agent result:user-A-Person ; prov:hadRole "author, committer"@en ] ;
```

I am trying to recreating an existing serialized data structure which contains the square brackets. I've managed to create the graph itself, but how do I add this in this way? I've tried using an RDFLib Collection, but no luck so far. Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are how [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)), and other related RDF serialisations, represent [blank nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_node). If you've recreated the structure and given that resource a URI, it won't be written like that, which is fine.

To create one in rdflib, use the [`BNode`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rdf_terms.html#bnodes) class. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph()

n = rdflib.BNode()

g.add((rdflib.URIRef('.'), rdflib.DC.hasPart, n))
g.add((n, rdflib.DC.title, rdflib.Literal('An anonymous resource')))

print(g.serialize(format='turtle').decode('utf-8'))
```

will generate:

```
@prefix ns1: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .

<.> ns1:hasPart [ ns1:title "An anonymous resource" ] .
```

That's not the only possible representation; for example, [N-Triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Triples) represents the same resource using an `_:` prefix:

```
_:genid1 <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> "An anonymous resource" .
<file:///tmp/> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/hasPart> _:genid1 .
```

Comment: That's just what I was after - thank you!